# Ler uma sequencia de caracteres com scanf()

Tags: c

Meu programa deve ler números grandes(*0<=X<=10^(100)*), o que estou fazendo é que ele leia/interprete os números digitados como `char` e armazene numa lista encadeada.

Meu programa estava bem, até eu colocar um `scanf("%d")`(cuja função é ler um numero, natural, de casos) acima do `scanf` que lê os números X...

Então, gostaria de saber como formatar a entrada do `scanf()` para que ele possa ler caracteres numéricos um a um e no fim ao pressionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Existe solução?

Parte do meu código:

```
scanf("%d", &t);

while(caso <= t)
{
   lista_ini = NULL;

   while((scanf("%c", &caract) == 1) && ((caract >= '0') && (caract <= '9')))
   {
      lista_ini = lst_insere(lista_ini, (caract - 48));
   }
...
```

Agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta prevenir que quando aparecer um `\n` ele pare de ler:

```
while((scanf("%c", &caract) == 1) && ((caract >= '0') && (caract <= '9')) && caract != '\n')
```

Ah para a limpeza do *buffer* antes da leitura podes deferir uma forma de "limpar" para começar a ler direitinho:

```
#DEFINE clearbuffer  while(getchar()!='\n');
```

e colocar o `clearbuffer` antes do `while`:

```
clearbuffer;
while((scanf("%c", &caract) == 1) && ((caract >= '0') && (caract <= '9')) && caract != '\n')
```

O `clearbuffer` serve para limpar o teu *buffer* para que não estejas a ler lixo que possa estar no *buffer* de leitura.

Mais uma coisa podes usar o `getchar` em vez do `scanf` no ciclo:

```
while(caract=getchar() && ((caract >= '0') && (caract <= '9')) && caract != '\n')
```

Comment: Consegui entender tudo, amigo! Obrigado

Comment: Só não consegui realizar usando o getchar, mas tudo bem.

Comment: Eu amanhã faço te um exemplo.